# iOS 9 - Missing UI elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios9

I am working on an older app that uses a UITextField subclass (let's call it CustomTextField) that is displayed in iOS 8.4 using xibs/storyboards. However, it is missing from the UI hierarchy in two out of three views in iOS 9.

- Successful case: Present in xib. No transition used.
- 1st failed case: A UITableViewCell subclass has a CustomTextField outlet connected through a storyboard. The table view's view controller is instantiated with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. Its `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method returns a non-nil cell, but CustomTextField is missing along with other elements of the custom cell (switches, image views, and labels).
- 2nd failed case: In the main view controller's `viewDidLoad`, CustomTextField and its superview are added through a xib using a category method `loadInstanceFromNib`, but the CustomTextField is missing from the UI Hierarchy:

  ```
  + (id)loadInstanceFromNib    
  {
     UIView *result;

     NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];

     for (id anObject in elements) {
         if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
             result = anObject;
             break;
         }
     }

     return result;
  }
  ```

I put a few breakpoints in CustomTextField.m. In both iOS 9 and 8.4, `awakeFromNib` is called. However, `willMoveToSuperview` is only called in 8.4 for both failed cases. This is the backtrace for `willMoveToSuperView`:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xde22fd, 0x00088ca9 Shop`-[CustomTextField willMoveToSuperview:](self=0x7be75690, _cmd=0x02115c1c, newSuperview=0x7be75160) + 57 at CustomTextField.m:39, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00088ca9 Shop`-[CustomTextField willMoveToSuperview:](self=0x7be75690, _cmd=0x02115c1c, newSuperview=0x7be75160) + 57 at CustomTextField.m:39
    frame #1: 0x0188be77 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 622
    frame #2: 0x0187e976 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    frame #3: 0x0186d87e UIKit`-[UIView _setTraitStorageSubviews:] + 647
    frame #4: 0x010ca608 Foundation`_NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
    frame #5: 0x010ca58d Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    frame #6: 0x0188f13f UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 168
    frame #7: 0x01100016 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 386
    frame #8: 0x01ab4d0e UIKit`-[_UIRelationshipTraitStorage applyRecordsMatchingTraitCollection:] + 1256
    frame #9: 0x01ab3a89 UIKit`-[NSObject(_UITraitStorageAccessors) _applyTraitStorageRecordsForTraitCollection:] + 202
    frame #10: 0x01871f84 UIKit`-[UIView _traitCollectionDidChangeFromOldCollection:toNewCollection:scaleDidChange:] + 62
    frame #11: 0x0187207f UIKit`-[UIView _wrappedProcessDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:scaleDidChange:forceNotification:] + 186
    frame #12: 0x0187215e UIKit`-[UIView _wrappedProcessDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:scaleDidChange:forceNotification:] + 409
    frame #13: 0x0187232c UIKit`__86-[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:]_block_invoke + 69
    frame #14: 0x01f75040 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 134
    frame #15: 0x018722df UIKit`-[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:] + 295
    frame #16: 0x01880773 UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 446
    frame #17: 0x018805ad UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 458
    frame #18: 0x0188c41d UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2068
    frame #19: 0x0187e976 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    frame #20: 0x0186d87e UIKit`-[UIView _setTraitStorageSubviews:] + 647
    frame #21: 0x010ca608 Foundation`_NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
    frame #22: 0x010ca58d Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    frame #23: 0x0188f13f UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 168
    frame #24: 0x01100016 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 386
    frame #25: 0x01ab4d0e UIKit`-[_UIRelationshipTraitStorage applyRecordsMatchingTraitCollection:] + 1256
    frame #26: 0x01ab3a89 UIKit`-[NSObject(_UITraitStorageAccessors) _applyTraitStorageRecordsForTraitCollection:] + 202
    frame #27: 0x01871f84 UIKit`-[UIView _traitCollectionDidChangeFromOldCollection:toNewCollection:scaleDidChange:] + 62
    frame #28: 0x0187207f UIKit`-[UIView _wrappedProcessDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:scaleDidChange:forceNotification:] + 186
    frame #29: 0x0187232c UIKit`__86-[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:]_block_invoke + 69
    frame #30: 0x01f75040 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 134
    frame #31: 0x018722df UIKit`-[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:] + 295
    frame #32: 0x0188f503 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 629
    frame #33: 0x02c84771 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    frame #34: 0x01614e47 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    frame #35: 0x01608925 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 403
    frame #36: 0x016172de QuartzCore`-[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 44
    frame #37: 0x01880f08 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 738
    frame #38: 0x01880c11 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutIfNeeded] + 83
    frame #39: 0x01998bc5 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1154
    frame #40: 0x01997d41 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 261
    frame #41: 0x0199559a UIKit`-[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 584
    frame #42: 0x01be54b4 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 334
    frame #43: 0x01be57c3 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 713
    frame #44: 0x01be5810 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView _navigationTransitionDidStop] + 55
    frame #45: 0x0186a162 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 206
    frame #46: 0x0186803d UIKit`+[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 334
    frame #47: 0x018834f4 UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) commitAnimations] + 36
    frame #48: 0x01be52b3 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 2798
    frame #49: 0x01be47bc UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 56
    frame #50: 0x019999b9 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3123
    frame #51: 0x01999d85 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 669
    frame #52: 0x0199aa01 UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    frame #53: 0x01b14700 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    frame #54: 0x0188f52a UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 668
    frame #55: 0x02c84771 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    frame #56: 0x01614e47 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    frame #57: 0x01608925 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 403
    frame #58: 0x0160877a QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 26
    frame #59: 0x01564c22 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 284
    frame #60: 0x015660b5 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 487
    frame #61: 0x0162e84d QuartzCore`+[CATransaction flush] + 52
    frame #62: 0x017f9a66 UIKit`-[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 39
    frame #63: 0x017fa9d9 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3182
    frame #64: 0x018138ee UIKit`__84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    frame #65: 0x017f8ffa UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    frame #66: 0x06ccfc9e FrontBoardServices`__37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    frame #67: 0x06ccf72f FrontBoardServices`__40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    frame #68: 0x06ce1d7c FrontBoardServices`__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30
    frame #69: 0x032fe050 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    frame #70: 0x032f3963 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    frame #71: 0x032f37bb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    frame #72: 0x032f2a5b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    frame #73: 0x032f288b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #74: 0x017f89b2 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 571
    frame #75: 0x017fc0b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
    frame #76: 0x00097bba Shop`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffb45f4) + 138 at main.m:14
    frame #77: 0x03d7fac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

It seems that `addSubview:` never gets called in iOS 9, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling size classes in the storyboard restored all missing subviews.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14003

Comment: Thanks! Disabling size classes on a problem xib file, then enabling them back worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and figured out that it a lot of my elements and constraints weren't installed to the any/any size class. (This is because the scene was put together in Compact/Regular size class) For some reason when the app was initially loaded it was only loading the elements that were in any/any.

After I added all of elements and constraints to any/any everything was instantiated and added to the view.